# Flow in Unlocked Package fails as Formula uses no namespace

Tags: visual-workflow, unlocked-package, namespace

I created a Namespaced Unlocked package out of that repo.

https://github.com/rsoesemann/salesforce-isv-cockpit/blob/master/force-app/main/default/flows/NotifySlackOnError.flow-meta.xml

It contains a Flow with a Formula that references packaged Fields, but all the other Field and Object references don't hardcode any namespace.

When the Flow runs from the Unlocked package, it fails because the formula fields cannot be referenced, and the values stay NULL.

[image]

I found that strange as other field references like `$Setup.Settings_c.txt_SlackChannel_c` also have no namespace but are correctly recognized.

**Is that a Flow Formula issue, or what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Phil that this is a bug manifesting in a variety of places within Flow metadata, where the Metadata API or packaging system fails to correctly resolve the component reference to the namespaced component. This *usually* manifests as functional failures in the installed package, although I think I remember one situation where the package failed to upload as well.

My team at Salesforce.org/Industries has worked with the Flow team in the past to address *some* of these bugs. It's hard to identify them all.

Because we heavily prioritize not including the package's namespace in metadata, we use dynamic injection of the namespace when we deploy metadata. This is done via a feature called [source transforms](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html#source-transforms) in CumulusCI.

In the past we have typically used a basic [find-and-replace](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html#find-and-replace-variable-injection) rubric with a token in the Flow metadata, like

```
<name>%%%NAMESPACE%%%AppNotification</name>
```

which gets injected with a blank (for regular orgs) or the actual namespace (for packaging). The `cumulusci.yml` configuration looks like this:

```
flows:
    deploy_packaging:
        options:
            deploy:
                transforms:
                    - transform: find_replace
                      options:
                          patterns:
                              - find: "%%%NAMESPACE%%%"
                                replace: my_namespace
```

That strategy doesn't work as well for Flows that are under active development because the token doesn't survive a round-trip through an org (push/pull) and has to be manually maintained in the required spots.

We recently introduced a more sophisticated strategy that supports XPath-based replacement, which would probably work well for this use case. XPath-based replacement does survive roundtrips through the org, because it targets the structural location in the metadata where the namespace needs to be injected.

Comment: I like that you're supporting (or trying to support) this flow "limitation" but it should be possible to deal with this using bare metal Salesforce CLI and packaging functionality. Is there any attempt to resolve this suite of bugs in the platform itself?

Comment: @PhilW Yeah, we've worked with the Flow team on the ones that bit us in the past. There's a million different places a namespaced component reference can appear, though. There are also a few situations where you might store a component reference in a part of the Flow XML that is technically text, not a component reference, so it won't get processed at all. (Ex. parameter values).

Comment: Apex handles this sort of thing. I just wished flow matched it in support for packaging.

Answer (score 4):

Flows do, indeed, need certain elements to include the namespace. I think it's a bug but we live with it by ensuring the namespace prefix is included where required. For us, this includes:

- Fields within $Record.
- Fields in custom settings in $Setup (though I see you didn't have that problem).
- Queried and assigned fields (Get Records, Assignment).
- Fields used in conditions.
- Object and field API names passed to the lookup component.
- Etc.

Fundamentally, flow handling of namespace is inconsistent with the rest of packaging and you should err on the side of providing the namespace prefix everywhere in the XML.